# How to put a horizontal divisor line with depth on the top side

Tags: android, user-interface

I'm making an activity to my app, and I have to divide some sections of my window with a line. I would like to do something like this:

[image]

I only tried with `android:elevation="2dp` on View in XML layout:

```
<View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="12dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:background="#E0E0E0"
        android:elevation="2dp"
        />
```

But this only put depth on the bottom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Higher elevation values will also add some shadow at the top of your View.

If you want more "shadow" at the top you can mimic it using a custom XML Drawable with white background and a top border of grey color and really small size (it can also be a gradient if you don't like the solid line):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- Background -->
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <!-- Top "line" -->
    <item android:gravity="top">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <size android:height="1dp" />
            <solid android:color="#ccc"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

If it's a `ViewGroup` you can also add a `View` with a small height value aligned right to its top with a grey background or gradient. It's simpler, but also a bit dirtier and worse for layout performance.